# problems updating row with Hibernate 6

Tags: hibernate-6.x

I am trying to write an update method with Hibernate 6. I logged the process and got no error. I debugged and got all fields as they should be. Yet the system is not updatig my row.

Here is the code:

```
public UpdateDTO toggle(Long id){
    Optional<ToDo> td = this.getById(id);
    if(td.isPresent()) {
        Boolean comp = !td.get().getFinished();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try (Session session = this.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            MutationQuery uq = session.createNativeMutationQuery("UPDATE to_do SET finished=:comp WHERE id=:id")
                                      .setParameter("id", id)
                                      .setParameter("comp", comp);
            int rows = uq.executeUpdate();
            transaction.commit();
            return UpdateDTO.builder()
                    .success(true)
                    .message(rows + " records was/were updated")
                    .todos(Arrays.asList(this.getById(id).get()))
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            return UpdateDTO.builder().success(false).message("Could not perform the update requested").build();
        }
    } else {
        return UpdateDTO.builder().success(false).message("Could not find a record with such id").build();
    }   
}
```

And this is the result when run on Postman

[capture of Postman response][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lov6.png)

Comment: Here is the response I got from Postman. The field 'finished' should be set to 'true', since it was originally 'false'.

{
    "success": true,
    "message": "1 records was/were updated",
    "todos": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "test1",
            "descriptionShort": "something",
            "descriptionLong": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse gravida imperdiet ligula, a consectetur lectus placerat at. ",
            "category": "other",
            "finished": false
        }
    ]
}